# Why the licence manager system like battle.net, steam, uplay age more interesting than isolated software installation

Tags: licensing, package-managers

I would like to understand why sofware developers tends to use a meta licence manager than a software dedicated licence.

Is it a question of security or for "customer experience"?

Thx for help

Answer (score 2):

Because if you try to roll your own licence management system, you **will** get it wrong.  Users will work out how to bypass your system and cracked copies of your software will be all over the internet.

It's better to use a well-tested third-party solution, written by people with more experience in software licence enforcement.

Comment: Ok, so, it is essentially for security reasons for you. Thx

Comment: @lelorrain7 Security and/or not needing to reinvent the wheel.